# Is it possible to get partitioned data using SQL?

Tags: java, sql, db2

I have a RDBMS table with a column `BIGINT` type and values are not sequential. I have a java program where I want each thread to get data as per `PARTITION_SIZE` i.e. I want a pair of column values like after doing `ORDER BY` on result,

```
Column_Value at Row 0 , Column_Value at Row `PARTITION_SIZE` 

Column_Value at Row `PARTITION_SIZE+1` , Column_Value at Row `2*PARTITION_SIZE` 

Column_Value at Row `2*PARTITION_SIZE+1` , Column_Value at Row  `3*PARTITION_SIZE`
```

Eventually, I will pass above value ranges  in a SELECT query's `BETWEEN` clause to get divided data for each thread.

Currently, I am able to do this partitioning via Java by putting all values in a `List` ( after getting all values from DB ) and then getting values at those specific indices - `{0,PARTITION_SIZE},{PARTITION_SIZE+1,2*PARTITION_SIZE}` ..etc but problem there is that `List` might have millions of records and is not advisable to store in memory.

So I was wondering if its possible to write such a query using SQL itself which would return me those ranges like below?

> row-1 -> minId , maxId
>
> row-2 -> minId , maxId
>
> ....

Database is DB2.

For example,

For table column values `1,2,12,3,4,5,20,30,7,9,11`  ,result of SQL query for a **partition size =2** should be `{1,2},{3,4} ,{5,7},{9,11},{12,20},{30}` .

Comment: Do I get your question right - you want to retrieve data from DB2 in parallel using multiple threads. And you ask how you could select the rows to get a  disjoint SELECTs?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have added an example to question and yes, I think you understood it correct.

Comment: Example that I have added have only one value for last set and I will take care of that situation in program since there is no end value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my eyes the mod() function would solve your problem and you could choose a dynamic number of partitions with it.

```
WITH numbered_rows_temp as ( 
SELECT rownumber() over () as rownum,
       col1,
       ...
       coln
  FROM table
  ORDER BY col1)

SELECT * FROM numbered_rows_temp
  WHERE mod(rownum, <numberofpartitions>) = 0
```

Fill in the appropriate  and change the result from 0 to  - 1 in your queries.

Comment: so basically with above query, if my table has only one column -`ÌD`of type `BIGINT` , I would get end values of partition range in table `numbered_rows_temp` and I can use `<=ID` for each `ID` from `numbered_rows_temp` table in my thread's SELECT sql? I mean, I will have to calculate start index separately for each range but that is OK.

Comment: no - forget about the ranges - in that case mod (modulo) does the calculation and in you got two partitions each odd row would be in partition 1 and each even row would be in partition 2.

Comment: I was not getting accurate results if I pass first query as inner query instead of a temp table but it works correctly if instead of doing `ORDER BY col1` separately , I do `over (ORDER BY col1)`

Answer (score 1):

[Michael Tiefenbacher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40047298/1227152) is probably more useful, as it avoids an extra query, but if you do want to determine ID ranges, this might work for you:

```
WITH parms(partition_size) AS (VALUES 1000) -- or whatever
SELECT 
    MIN(id), MAX(id), 
    INT(rn / parms.partition_size) partition_num
FROM (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn 
    FROM yourtable
) t , parms
GROUP BY INT(rn / parms.partition_size)
```

Comment: Thanks , you solution works too and offers range values in same row.